# Java convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 with correct unicode characters

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have some ISO-8859-1 text that I have tried to convert to UTF-8 but end up with some characters that are not mapped correctly.
I have been using plethora of standard built-in Java charset conversion which are pretty much all based on Charset.decode and the built-in CharsetDecoder.

This leads to two problems:

- I have some characters that look fine in ISO but crap in Java since I output in UTF-8 as do most java apps.
- [I cannot insert into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762416/cannot-insert-non-latin-symbols-in-mysql) even though its set to UTF-8

For MySQL I get the exception (see link above):

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x9Esk\xC3\xA9...' for column 'b' at row 1

**Is there a Java iconv or better Character decoder/mapper than whats built-in?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you certain that you have ISO-8859-1?  You might have some Win-1252, which can be sorta close except for a dozen or so characters.  That \x9E raises that suspiscion with me.

Try labeling your source as WIN-1252 and it should convert correctly.

Comment: you are champion of life. I ran iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 and viola the problems went away. Strange thing is both my browser (Firefox) and my text editor told me it was ISO-8859-1

Comment: The "real ISO-8859-1 verses Microsoft ISO-8859-1" has caused me several years of debugging (and nightmares) as we moved our software into Europe.  I'm glad you could learn from my bad expierence.