# How to search tamil word in indexed content in solr

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am using nutch and solr for crawling.nutch crawled and indexed the contents from Tamil language website.but during search in solr, i give Tamil words ,the given word was ***converted into unicode***.so,unable to find the particular content in the indexed documents.

Comment: Can you attach a picture or give some examples? It helps us to understand the question better. What do you mean by `converted to unicode`?

Comment: Thanks for reply --After Crawling Tamil contents from website using nutch,In solr query box - i give query as *:* ,it will display all the tamil documents. but give tamil words in query box for example:விளையாட்டு ,solr does not display the specific document ,because it converted into some  unicode and the search the documents.

Comment: I still didn't get what you say. What is the name of the Tamil font used? Is it a Unicode font or not?

Comment: Latha.ttf - Tamil Unicode Font

Comment: Your question is still confusing. Can you rephrase it? Since your font is Unicode, it is compatible with most applications. Check your application's settings regarding encoding. Change the encoding to utf-8 in case if it is ASCII or other encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be an encoding issue. try this solutions
[UTF-8 characters not showing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825793/utf-8-characters-not-showing-properly)
Tamil character spaces in unicode block are in between 2944 to 3071