# how to read and store non-English character in java on windows os

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am dealing with a Brazilian customer where the data is in Portuguese language.

My application is responsible to read the data through web-service calls and store it in our database. The issue that I am currently facing is the Portuguese characters are not getting identified as it is and is stored in my database as a special character.

I am using MySQL database with all tables configured as collation UTF-8. I tried manually inserting Portuguese character into my database and it worked. So I am suspecting its java who is converting the Portuguese characters into special character.

Also, my application is using Hibernate for database operations.

I am able to get the character as I see in logs and the issue reside while trying to store that data in database.

```
Eg: Original characters: Gerãt
    Database characters: GerÃ£t
```

What configurations or setting or changes I need to do to my database so that I can capture the data in Portuguese language as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in my case:

Add environment variable **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** instead of **_JAVA_OPTIONS** with value as

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be database issue, but an application configuration issue.

Few pointers to help :

- Check the webservice implementation if it can accept Portugese chars
- Check the encoding in your web container. For example Tomcat
- Add logs to find out where the Portugese chars are lost.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can see the words in proper format in logs but in database it is corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your hibernate configuration to:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.useUnicode">true</property> 
<property name="connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
<property name="connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
```

If that doesn't work, try adding `UTF-8` to your `characterEncoding` in your JDBC url.

Also, this question might help you: [Cannot insert non latin symbols in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762416/cannot-insert-non-latin-symbols-in-mysql)

Comment: I tried above suggestion but it did not work. Also I tried executing command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%'` as given in link and i can see result as: `collation_connection     latin1_swedish_ci
collation_database      utf8_general_ci
collation_server latin1_swedish_ci` Is this an issue?

Comment: I think that might be the issue, shouldn't `collation_connection` and `collation_server` both be `utf8_general_ci` as `collation_database`? Try changing those to utf8 and post the results here. Check Ben's anwser on [How to configure global charset on MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8288/how-to-configure-global-charset-on-mysql) if you need a hand on how to change those values.

Comment: One strange thing is when i run my code through eclipse i can see the data getting inserted correctly but when i run it as jar it fails... To make it run through eclipse i only changed encoding for content-types (eclipse->windows->preferences->general->content-types) to UTF-8 and it worked so I am not getting is it really database issue?

Comment: Try fetching some data from the db and just print it to `Console.Out`. Run that "print" in Eclipse and then run it on a terminal (Also, what is your OS and which encoding is it using?). The results differ from Eclipse to the terminal one? If so, it just might be an issue with JVM using an encoding other than UTF8

Comment: Yes.... Got the solution.... problem was with JVM... Added environment variable: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` instead of `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with value as `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`